# PHP Proxy for getting other domain content

Tags: php

Can I write a PHP file (index.php) that when someone point it browser to

http://www.domain.org/some?params=a&b=1

it returns the content of

http://www.OTHERdomain.org/some?params=a&b=1

Should I use culr?

Comment: You could go with file_get_contents(url) if you have the allow url fopen set to 'TRUE' in your php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php#88055, this is the code you need:

```
<?php
    // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);     
?>
```

Comment: I added an echo $output before closing.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a page called `proxy.php` or something like that that takes a URL as the parameter. Then, you can replace `domain.org` with `otherdomain.org` in the URL. Then use CURL to get the contents and return it.